# using a dictionary to filter a list of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

let's say I have a data structure like so (list of objects):

```
[
 <--
    Name: Bob
    Job: Programmer
    Location: Salem
  -->,
 <--
    Name: Steve
    Job: Sales
    Location: New York
 -->,
 <--
    Name: Jeff
    Job: Programmer
    Location: New York
 -->
]
```

Now let's say I have a web form that will give back a dictionary, where each key will refer to a field in the object. For example, let's just say I get a dictionary back like this:

```
{"Name": [""], "Job": ["Programmer"], "Location": ["Salem", "New York"]}
```

this is intended to return all the programmers in the salem and New York location: Bob and Jeff. It will always be a dictionary of list of strings. I just want to check if the string value of the object contains this string.

The problem is in iterating over each entry of the dictionary and making sure each object matches ALL specifications of the dictionary.
This is my current code, which logically only makes a list of objects that contains any objects that contain ANY of the parameters, which is not what I want:

```
return_list = []
filter_dictionary = dict(request.form)
for row in data:
  for key, value in filter_dictionary.iteritems():
    for obj in value:
      if obj in str(getattr(row, key)):
        return_list.append(row)
return return_list
```

I'm certain there must be a smarter and better way to do this, perhaps with something involving sets. How would I go about that?

The return value should ultimately be a list of objects, as in the original example, but only containing the objects that met all specifications of the `filter_dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

I think that first you need to change your input:

`"Name": [""]` suggests to look for programmers with an empty string for a name. I think you should have `[]` instead of `[""]`, or something like that.

Given that, what about this?

```
return_list = []
for row in data:
    if all((getattr(row, k) in v) or (not v) for k, v in filter_dictionary.iteritems()):
        return_list.append(thing)
```

Your current code is equivalent to this:

```
return_list = []
for row in data:
    if any((getattr(row, k) in v) or (not v) for k, v in filter_dictionary.iteritems()):
        return_list.append(thing)
```

I think that the above is more or less the best way (apart from using a database).

But since you suggested sets...

First you need to ensure your class for rows in data supports hashing:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name, Location, Job):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Location = Location
        self.Job = Job
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person({}, {}, {})".format(self.Name, self.Location, self.Job)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.Name == other.Name and self.Location == other.Location and self.Job == other.Job
     def __hash__(self):
         return hash(repr(self))
```

Then do this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import product
>>> data
[Person(Bob, Salem, Programmer), Person(Steve, New York, Sales), Person(Jeff, New York, Programmer)]
>>> filter_dictionary = {"Name": [], "Job": ["Programmer"], "Location": ["Salem", "New York"]}
>>> fd = {key: (value or [getattr(person, key) for person in data]) for key, value in filter_dictionary.items()}
>>> fd
{'Job': ['Programmer'], 'Location': ['Salem', 'New York'], 'Name': ['Bob', 'Steve', 'Jeff']}
>>> items = list(fd.iteritems())
>>> new = []
>>> for p in product(*map(itemgetter(1), items)):
        temp = {}
        for index, value in enumerate(p):
            temp[items[index][0]] = value
        new.append(temp)

>>> new
[{'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'Salem', 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'Salem', 'Name': 'Steve'}, {'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'Salem', 'Name': 'Jeff'}, {'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'New York', 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'New York', 'Name': 'Steve'}, {'Job': 'Programmer', 'Location': 'New York', 'Name': 'Jeff'}]
>>> possible_matches = {Person(**kwargs) for kwargs in new}
>>> ts & set(data)
{Person(Bob, Salem, Programmer), Person(Jeff, New York, Programmer)}
```

As you can see, this is much longer and more cumbersome. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Others may give more concise solutions, but I think the closest tweak to your existing code is like this:

```
return_list = []
filter_dictionary = dict(request.form)
for row in data:
  match = True # we set to False if any attribute doesn't match
  for key, value in filter_dictionary.items():
    attrmatch = False # we need at least one match per attribute
    for obj in value:
      if obj in str(getattr(row, key)): attrmatch = True
    if not attrmatch: match = False
  if match: return_list.append(row)
```

Comment: I believe the only problem with this solution is that it only matches one of the things in the list. That is to say, if it contains New York OR Salem, then add it to the list. Maybe I implemented it wrong but it seems like it is having this behavior